# i'm building an application for blind people so i need to read button input

Tags: android

I am building an application for blind people. I need to read a button input, but before it is read, I want to play a audio about the button content. So when the finger is on top of the button I need to play the audio, i.e the word which given to the button.

How can I do it?

```
        @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         getSupportActionBar().hide();// this is the code for the hide applicatoin name
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //to hide the notification bar

        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        speakButton.setOnKeyListener(this);
         tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a touch listener then check the type of event to see if its an  ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP event.

```
speakButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           //play sound
       } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          //do action
       }

       return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: this is OK for one input events {OK for ontuchlistner } but i wont to catch ontuchlistner and same button longpresslistner so how can i overcome this problem please help me

Comment: you should write another question and show the code you have allready written so I can help you better